# Duda con instalación y funcionamiento de Composer

Tags: symfony, composer

Me surge una duda sobre la instalación de Composer. Según veo se puede instalar con el instalador de windows lo cual permite usarlo desde cualquier directorio (según se indica en https://getcomposer.org/download/). También he visto en varios tutoriales de Symfony que Composer se instala mediante `$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php`. Con esto obtenemos un archivo llamado composer.phar que se recomienda (en la instalación de Symfony) moverlo en la carpeta raiz del proyecto a la misma altura que el archivo composer.json. 
Mi dudas son estas: 
-El archivo composer.phar ¿que es? ¿Un ejecutable como un .exe?
-Si es un ejecutable (tipo .exe) debo duplicarlo para tenerlo en cada proyecto de symfony?
-Y finalmente... a la hora de ejecutar un comando de composer ¿como sabe composer en que proyecto estoy? Es decir si yo tengo "proyecto1" y "proyecto2" con un composer.phar en cada uno cuando hago instalo vendors con `$ php composer.phar install` ¿en que proyecto va a instalarlos? ¿en el primero?¿en el segundo?¿o en los dos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El archivo composer.phar es el archivo binario de Composer, se utiliza de manera directa si realizás la instalación manual de Composer, si en Windows lo instalás a través del instalador que proporciona Composer, no es necesario configurar nada, ya que el instalador lo realiza por vos y se configura de manera global para todos los proyectos.

Al instalarlo con el instalador de Windows, cuando quieras realizar una instalación de un proyecto, sólo deberás ejecutar el siguiente comando en la carpeta del proyecto:

```
composer install
```

Comment: ¿Y en el caso de que se instale mediante "$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php"  ¿se debe copiar el "composer.phar" en cada proyecto que tengamos tal y como se indica en tutoriales como "https://librosweb.es/libro/symfony_2_x/capitulo_3/instalando_una_distribucion_de_symfony2.html"? ¿En caso de que tu respuesta sea si, podrías decirme por que funciona asi? Al no estar familiarizado con .phar me cuesta un poco entender por que se usa asi.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos viendo cada pregunta:

1. Qué es Composer.phar?: yendo a la documentación de [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#locally) nos dicen: "Este archivo es el 
   binario de composer. Es un archivo PHAR (PHP archive), el cual es un archivo de empaquetado o formato de archivo (archivo de archivar) para PHP que puede ser ejecutado desde la línea de comandos, entre otras cosas". Si vamos a la documentación de PHP [php phar](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php) nos dice que son una manera de empaquetar aplicaciones php enteras en un solo archivo. Lo que nos da como conclusión que el composer.phar es un empaquetado con todo el código fuente de las operaciones que lleva a cabo el composer para el manejo de paquetes como tal, de manera que solo tengas que tener ese archivo para operar.
2. En qué proyecto se ejecuta: Acá debes entender más es como funcionan las rutas relativas, te explico. Si yo ejecuto una aplicación (hablando de windows) en C:\programas\myapp\ el programa entiende que su ruta principal es esa, si el programa quiere acceder a un archivo ubicado en una carpeta subsiguiente por ejemplo, C:\programas\myapp\img\foto1.jpg éste no tiene que indicar la ruta absoluta "toda la ruta" para acceder al mismo, sino que podemos decir "img\foto1.jpg" porque en éste caso se entiende que la ruta indicada es a partir de la ruta en la que fue ejecutado el programa o sea "C:\programas\myapp".

   Dicho ésto, cuando ejecutas el comando composer install en el directorio "C:\programas\myapp" lo primero que hace es buscar el archivo "composer.json" (es el archivo que describe todas las dependencias/paquetes de tu aplicación más metadata del proyecto), pero dónde lo busca? pues lo busca a partir de la ruta relativa a donde fue ejecutado el comando, o sea "C:\programas\myapp", es por ello que si lo ejecutas en la carpeta proyecto1 buscará el archivo composer.json de esa carpeta y si lo ejecutas en proyecto2 buscara el archivo composer.json de esa carpeta, además de descargar las librerías y realizar las configuraciones necesarias (o sea crear la carpeta vendors, etc..) en la carpeta en que fue ejecutado.
3. Debes duplicarlo? R: No, si te fijas en la misma documentación de composer indican que puedes tenerlo referenciado en la variable path de tu sistema operativo para usarlo en cualquier directorio desde la línea de comandos.

   Cuando te dicen que lo descargues con curl y lo coloques en cada carpeta es porque no lo están colocando en un ruta accesible globalmente por el sistema operativo, ya que si ejecutas el cmd, por ejemplo en la ruta "c:\users", y ejecutas composer te dirá que no existe el comando, caso contrario que lo ejecutes en donde descargaste el composer.phar con curl (es por las rutas relativas ya que si ejecutaste el cmd en la ruta donde descargaste el composer.phar, éste buscará primero el comando en su ruta de ejecución y luego en los directorios de la variable path). La variable path del sistema operativo se utiliza para indicarle dónde debe buscar los programas a ajecutar, si mi variable path tiene las ruta "c:\programa";"c:\oracle";"c:\epicgames y en la carpeta epicgames existe un programa llamado miprograma.exe cuando en el cmd ejecuto el comando miprograma el sistema va a todas esas rutas que están colocadas en la variable path buscando uno que se llame programa.exe, en éste caso lo encuentra en la carpeta epicgames y lo ejecuta. Pasa lo mismo con el composer.phar, cuando se hace la instalación con el installer para windows se coloca en la variable path la ruta en la que fue instalado el mismo.

Espero que te quede más claro ésto.

Saludos.

Comment: entiendo mejor ahora el funcionamiento de composer gracias a tu explicacion. Aún me queda alguna duda. Dices que instalando composer con el installer de windows la ruta de de composer queda almacenada en el path y solo tendría que moverme al directorio donde quiera ejecutar un comando para que sea efectivo allí. Esto lo veo claro (si me equivoco por favor corrígeme).

Comment: Pero la duda ahora es esta: cuando instalo con "$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php" en digamos C:/xampp/htdocs/proyecto1 obtendré el archivo composer.phar en la carpeta proyecto1. Ahora situandome en la consla en esta ruta puedo ejecutar el "composer install". ¿Que pasa si ahora voy en la consola a C:/xampp/htdocs/proyecto2 y ejecuto de nuevo "composer install"? ¿se instalarán los vendors en "proyecto2? ¿o tengo que añadir en el path la ruta donde esta composer instalado en proyecto1 para que sea efectivo? 
Te agradezo tu ayuda.

Comment: ¿Que pasa si ahora voy en la consola a C:/xampp/htdocs/proyecto2 y ejecuto de nuevo "composer install"?: Acá debería indicarte error ya que no está el composer.phar.
¿o tengo que añadir en el path la ruta donde esta composer instalado en proyecto1 para que sea efectivo?: Pues lo puedes hacer así, o descargas el composer en una ruta más general y esa ruta es la que agregas a la variable path, así lo usas en ambos proyectos.

Comment: Si lo dejas en la carpeta del proyecto1 y metes esa ruta en la variable path te va a funcionar cuando vayas a la carpeta proyecto2 y le des composer  install, el tema es que si eliminas el proyecto 1 por xalgún motivo tendras que descargar de nuevo eso.. Por lo que de nuevo lo ideal es que tengas el composer instalado en no se C:\archivos de programa\composer y esa es al ruta que metes en la variable path (así lo hace el instalador para windows, no recuerdo la ruta completa pero es una ruta general).

Comment: Gracias, me ayudaste mucho!